# egit commit lost after checkout

Tags: egit, vcs-checkout

Using egit, I wanted to switch back to a previous version just for some minutes. So I **committed my new code** and **checked out an earlier version**.

Now that I have finished looking through the older stuff, I want to go "back" to the newest, local commit from before. However, History view seems to have forgotten that I made a commit just before, going back is not possible.

Also, *Team->Replace with->Commit* doesn't offer my latest commit. It seems like the commit was overwritten. Where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Team->Reset*, it's possible to go back to your local commits:

[image] (img from eclipse.wiki)